# Deploy artifacts to non maven Java EE web application

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee

I have an existing Java EE web application which is not using maven, and currently there are no plans to migrate it to maven. However, some dependencies are using maven and saved to the local repository and an artifactory.

Is there a way to let the Java EE web application deploy artifacts from a maven repository? Currently I am able to compile the projects in Eclipse but get a NoClassDefFoundError on runtime.

Thanks!
Omri

Comment: Migrate it to maven and that will make your life easier.

Comment: That's not up to me and not possible unfortunately...

Comment: Add required libraries to the `WEB-INF/lib` of your web application project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel you, I am not a Maven fan but sometimes you can't escape it.  I'm not aware of any framework that would facilitate this. There would be some interesting class loader issues one would need to overcome to facilitate loading JARs (from any source, not just Maven caches) into a running EE application, especially if the JARs are used by container managed classes. In that case the framework would need to load itself before the web app deployment phase. I'm not sure the EE spec even provides for that. You are going to have to do as @Gas suggests and package these libraries in your WEB-INF/lib folder of your WAR. I've done this in the past, and it can be a bit of a manual pain in the a$$. What I have done it start with an environment that has a clean .m2 directory and then pull down the maven deps and manually move the JARs from the .m2 directory into the WEB-INF/lib folder. This is really a last resort if you can't use maven.

Comment: Thanks, and thank @Gas. This is what I'll do - Copy the jars into the WEB-INF/lib folder. Thanks for the help!